# The 'Id' property on 'Table1' could not be set to a 'System.Byte[]' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Guid'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oracle12c

I am using Code First with `Oracle 12c`.  I have a class

```
public class Table1
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string SomeOtherStuff { get; set; }
}
```

Entity Framework converts Id to `RAW`

```
CREATE TABLE "FB"."Media" 
   (    "Id" RAW(16) NOT NULL ENABLE, ...
```

So now if I do this:

```
var list = db.Table1.SqlQuery("select * from Table1")).ToList();
```

I get an error

> The 'Id' property on 'Table1' could not be set to a 'System.Byte[]' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Guid'}`

**Edit:** I am using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework 6.121.2.0

Comment: Tip: SO doesn't use the triple backtick flavour of markdown, we use 4 spaces indentation (or select the code and press Ctrl+K) :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your Oracle EF provider maps `Guid` to the `Raw` type, but in turn, the `Raw` is mapped to a byte array.

You could try specifying the column type yourself, if your provider supports it (depending on your provider, it might not).

```
public class Table1
{

  [Column("Id", TypeName="VARCHAR(50)")]
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string SomeOtherStuff { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: did you try this method yourself?

Comment: No, I haven't. Whether this solution works or not depends on the actual EF provider, which is not mentioned in the original post.
This is one of the ways of specifying the column type for a specific property in EF, so _if_ the provider used by the OP supports it, it should work (see the part in parenthesis in my original post).

Comment: I am using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework 6.121.2.0